# Detecting if Intel MKL is enabled in Visual Studio project's properties

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intel-mkl

I am working on a project where Intel MKL is nice to have, but not available on all the targeted platforms, so I have to check for its presence to behave accordingly.

I have enabled the `Intel Performance Libraries` in my Visual Studio project's properties, as explained in [Compiling and Linking Intel® Math Kernel Library with Microsoft* Visual C++*](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-math-kernel-library-intel-mkl-compiling-and-linking-with-microsoft-visual-cc) and in [Intel® Math Kernel Library (Intel® MKL) 2018 Getting Started](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-math-kernel-library-intel-mkl-2018-getting-started) but I'm not getting any of the preprocessor definitions described in [Using Predefined Preprocessor Symbols for Intel® MKL Version-Dependent Compilation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-linux-developer-guide-using-predefined-preprocessor-symbols-for-intel-mkl-version-dependent-compilation), e.g. `__INTEL_MKL__` is not defined.

Any ideas how I can have these? Or any other means to detect Intel MKL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way that is a good compromise yet not very elegant.

Apparently we can check values of Property Pages settings in Build Events. After discovering a macro named `UseIntelMKL` I decided to tie a `config.h` to the value of it accordingly, and use the preprocessor directives defined in this `config.h` instead.

Here is roughly the script that acts as `Pre-build Event`. I am basically defining `__INTEL_MKL__` myself in `config-mkl.h`.

```
if "$(UseIntelMKL)"=="Parallel" (
  xcopy /Y /I $(ProjectDir)config-mkl.h $(ProjectDir)config.h
) else (
  xcopy /Y /I $(ProjectDir)config-nomkl.h $(ProjectDir)config.h
)
```

Comment: This is not a solution, but a hack, my friend. :) I posted a solution.

Comment: Please read my question and my comments, it's about `detecting if Intel MKL is enabled in Visual Studio project's properties`. Project is Windows-only and you're suggesting to put in place another build system. What I did here is simply, well, `detecting if Intel MKL is enabled in Visual Studio project's properties`.

Comment: CMake is not another build system. It is a build system generator. It helps for example on Windows to make a command line build for example and a VS solution etc. But it would allow you to keep multiple versions of MKL on your machine. And allow you also to build with the intel compiler, .... But, hey, it works for you, so. No hard feelings. Good luck with your endevours.