# Visual Studio mkl_link_tool.exe linking error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to compile a very simple C++ code in my newly installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 and Intel Parallel Studio XE (shipped with the MKL Library 2020). Basically the code creates a 3x3 sparse idendity matrix handle in the CSR format and then destroy the handle:

```
#include "mkl.h"
#include "mkl_spblas.h"
int main(void)
{
    const MKL_INT n = 3;
    MKL_INT ia[3] = {0, 1, 2},ja[3] = {0, 1, 2};
    double a[3] = {1., 1., 1. };
    sparse_matrix_t csrA; 
    mkl_sparse_d_create_csr(&csrA, SPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ZERO, n, n, ia, ia + 1, ja, a);
    mkl_sparse_destroy(csrA);
    return;
}
```

I did what [this link](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/mkl-windows-developer-guide/top/programming-with-intel-math-kernel-library-in-integrated-development-environments-ide/configuring-your-integrated-development-environment-to-link-with-intel-math-kernel-library/configuring-the-microsoft-visual-c-c-development-system-to-link-with-intel-mkl.html) (as well as [this link](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/mkl-windows-developer-guide/top/linking-your-application-with-the-intel-math-kernel-library/linking-quick-start/automatically-linking-a-project-in-the-visual-studio-integrated-development-environment-with-intel-mkl/automatically-linking-your-microsoft-visual-c-c-project-with-intel-mkl.html)) describes to configure the Project (except for Step 6, as I can't find the "Custom Build Setup" in the Visual Studio so I configure intead in "Custom Build Step").

I used the [Intel Math Kernel Library Link Line Advisor](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor.html) to configure the include directories and the library directories (I selected the MS C\C++ Compiler, Intel(R)64 architeture, Dynamic linking, 32-bit integer interface and sequential threading layer).

Thanks to @john, I managed to make some small progress. But I'm still getting this error:

```
Error   MSB3073 The command "mkl_link_tool.exe -libs -c ms_c -a intel64 -i ilp64 -p no 2> NUL" exited with code 9009.   ConsoleApplication1 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Platforms\x64\PlatformToolsets\v142\ImportBefore\Intel.Libs.MKL.v142.targets    64
```

I've succesfully run some codes calling MKL libraries under linux system before, but I'm still fairly new to the MSVS (as well as MKL) so I really appreaciate any help. I've read some similar topic on the internet (for example, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51481915/detecting-if-intel-mkl-is-enabled-in-visual-studio-projects-properties)) but still can't get the work done.

Comment: Device: Dell XPS 13-7390; OS: Windows 10 Pro, Version 1909; Intel Parallel Studio XE: cluster edition, 2020 update 1(I don't know where to download a free composer edition under a student license); Microsoft Visual Studio : Community 2019, Version 16.6.3

Comment: Both of those warnings seem relevant. I can't say what the first means but the second implies that MKL is a 64 bit library but you're trying to build a 32 bit program. That's never going to work.

Comment: @john Thanks for the reply. I notice that but even if I selected the 64 bit integer in the MKL Link Line Advisor, I still get the same warning.

Comment: The problem is not MKL, the problem is Visual Studio. You need to make sure you pick the x64 platform for your build.

Comment: @john Thank you but after I make it as x64 it still can't compile. Also for the record my MKLROOT is at C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2020.1.216\windows\mkl.

Comment: [compiler-construction] is for questions about *writing* compilers, not using them. (Also, I don't believe you are using [gcc], and if that is true then that tag is also misleading.)

Comment: @Lau_Yiyeung Do you still get the same `Warning LNK4272` after switching to x64?

Comment: @rici Thank you for the reminding, I removed the tag. But it would be even better if I could do all this in a command prompt with gcc :)

Comment: @john No, now there is only the MSB3073 error, no other warnings or errors.

Comment: @Lau_Yiyeung Well that's progress. Apparently this latest error means that Visual Studio cannot find the mkl_link_tool.exe file. Why that would be and how you would fix it I'm not really sure.

Comment: You could try to open the IDE by using `devenv /useenv` and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the same problem has been discussed at the mkl forum:https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-oneAPI-Math-Kernel-Library/MKL-2020-1-VS2019-linking-bug/m-p/1153138

Comment: Thank you! This fixes my problem.